# How to install tcsh onto a server without using sudo?

Tags: command-line, server

I tried running a bash script on a server, but it gave me the error `-bash: ./run-jaccard.sh: /bin/tcsh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. I believe I need to install tcsh somehow and that will get rid of the error. The required command is `sudo apt-get install csh`, but I can't use sudo in the server, I don't have permissions. Is there another way I can install tcsh? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nope.  Ask the server owner to give you permission to install it or have them do it for you.

Comment: You could maybe compile it yourself, but there's no way you're getting it to `/bin` without administrator help.